# Vscode Autocomplete is adding extra ={} to variables

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

In vscode, while editing a tsx file that contains React / Next.js code

When i write <demoComponent about={d
and open suggestions i get all my variables for eg : demoVar
and when i select demoVar instead of getting demoVar i Get demoVar={}|

how to solve this
Example : [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue for a couple of days until I removed this extension [JavaScript and Typescript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next)

Downgrading this extension to **v5.0.202301090** also works.

Comment: Happened to me also, after removing this nightly extension it worked!